# Convert the structure of a column in a data frame to character if if it exist, otherwise don't worry

Tags: r

I am creating a function that will read in several comma delimited files into R before I mutate them to add on a few columns and then export it again to use the files in another model. There exist one particular field in some of the files that contains numbers but the model denotes it as a string (with "" around it). Naturally R obviously reads this as a numeric field and so I want to convert it to a character if the column name exists.

The code within the function I have tried is the following:

```
with(df, if("name of column" %in% colnames(df)) as.character)
```

unfortunately this doesn't work. Thank you in advance!

P.s. I have code further along in my script that will add on the "" to all character fields, so obtaining those is not a problem, just the actual conversion to a character field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write up a simple name checker function:

```
    check_names<- function(df, col_name = "Species"){
  if(col_name %in% names(df)){
    df[[col_name]]<- as.character(df[[col_name]])

  }

  df
}
str(check_names(iris,"Species"))
```

**EDIT**

The modified function below will work for several columns:

```
check_names<- function(df, col_names = NULL){
  if(all(col_names %in% names(df))){

    df[,col_names]<- sapply(df[,col_names],as.character)

  }

  df
}
```

Result using the above:

```
str(check_names(iris,c("Species","Sepal.Length")))
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

Original result:

```
data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" .


# non existent names
str(check_names(iris,"nope"))
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: This is not very generalisable(returns a matrix for some reason if used with `tidy` code). If you need to use it with `tidy` code, need to revise it.

Comment: It did work for me as I don't think I am using tidy code, but would I be able to extend the function so I can have Col_Name = a vector which consists of several column names? or it there another potential method? Thank you in advance

Comment: I edited to make it possible to use several columns. Note that you will need to add some error checks or sanity checks to make sure errors are thrown if a column name doesn't exist.